# Adding different randomly generated numbers in an Excel sheet with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, excel

So i have an excel sheet which i am adding data to. I have made headers

```
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim xlRange As Excel.Range
        Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value
        Dim rNum As Random = New Random

        xlApp = New Excel.Application
        xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
        xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")
        xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

        With xlWorkSheet
            .Range("A1").Value = "col1"
            .Range("B1").Value = "col2"
            .Range("C1").Value = "col3"
            .Range("D1").Value = "col4"
            .Range("E1").Value = "col5"
            .Range("F1").Value = "col6"
        End With
```

what i would like to do for col5 is have every row and individual, randomly generated number using rNum to do it. So far i have been able to populate multiple rows in the column but it is the same number and not unique

Any advice on this?

**EDIT**

The only code i had was this:

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("E2:E10").Value = rNum.Next()
```

Comment: This should be pretty easy to solve. Can you show the code that you wrote which populates multiple rows in the column but shows the same number over and over.

Comment: Updated @ChicagoMike

Comment: I haven't run your code, but it appears that you need to loop through each of the elements in your range, calling rNum.Next() each time.  Right now, you're only calling it once - hence, you're getting the same value for each cell in your range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to set a different value for every cell:

```
For i As Integer = 2 To 10
    xlWorkSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = rNum.Next()
Next i
```

Sincerely, Doom Guy with 100% health

Comment: Worked like a charm! hopefully we can both ascend to God Mode Doom Guy one day

Comment: At the moment i will try getting more Rep with `IDKFA`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
xlWorkSheet.Range("E2:E10").Value = rNum.Next()
```

Try using

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = xlWorkSheet.Range("E2:E10")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    rCell.Value = rNum.Next()
Next rCell
```

Does that do the trick?